# JFrame components being able to call paintComponent through repaint, although using flowlayout

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jframe, paintcomponent

I have a JFrame in FlowLayout with multiple JLabels added to it, but when I call repaint on the JLabels, their paintComponent is not being called. If I remove the FlowLayout, only the last JLabel added shows up and repaints properly. I tried to use a panel but it didn't work. I'm not sure I'm using it properly though.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RacingLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
                jframe.setTitle("Racing letters");
                jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //jframe.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - jframe.getWidth()) / 2);
                int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - jframe.getHeight()) / 2);
                jframe.setLocation(x, y);
                jframe.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
                FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
                jframe.setLayout(fl);
                //jframe.setLayout(null);
                jframe.setVisible(true);    

                StringBuffer[] stringBufferArray = new StringBuffer[20];
                char ch = 'A';

                int yy = 20;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    stringBufferArray[i] = new StringBuffer("");
                    BufferThread bt = new BufferThread(stringBufferArray[i], ch, 10, yy);
                    //pane.add(bt);
                    jframe.add(bt);

                    new Thread(bt).start();
                    ch++;
                    yy += 20;
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

..

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class BufferThread extends JLabel implements Runnable {

    char ch;
    StringBuffer sb;
    int x,y;

    BufferThread(StringBuffer sb, char ch,int x, int y) {
        this.sb = sb;
        this.ch = ch;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sb.append(ch);
            System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + ch);
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(500));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BufferThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + ch);
        //System.out.println("aaaa");
        //stem.out.println(sb);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        //if (sb.toString().indexOf("E") < 0)
            g2.drawString(sb.toString(), x, y);

    }

}
```

Comment: Swing components shouldn't be used outside the Event Dispatch Thread, so you should do this differently. I suggest using a Swing Timer.

Comment: By the way, it appears the sizes of the components stay unchanged at 0x0. For that reason, `repaint` finds it unnecessary to call `paintComponent`.

Comment: Don't override JLabel to implement a Thread or do custom painting.

Comment: @Lonenebula I think you hit the nail on the head there...do you know why though?

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is that the `JLabel` isn't providing any information back to the frame's layout manager about how big it would like to be.  Nor is it actually telling the frame's layout manager that it's updated and needs to be resized.

Why you're trying to paint text on a label is beyond me, seen as that's what a label does by design.

You should avoid using `Thread` when dealing with Swing components and should use `javax.swing.Timer` and `SwingWorker` where possible.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Ticker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ticker();
    }

    public Ticker() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame.add(new TickerLabel());
                frame.setSize(100, 100);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TickerLabel extends JLabel {

        private int counter;

        public TickerLabel() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (counter > 4) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    } else {
                        String text = getText();
                        text += (char)(((int)'A') + counter);
                        setText(text);
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Nicely done! I didn't inspect his code well enough to realize why the size wouldn't change. He wanted the delay to be random though, such that multiple labels would compete.

Comment: @Lonenebula I'm sure the OP can figure out how to achieve that ;)